# unicode "aware" std::getline

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding

Well I'm testing how to write a C++ application that actually can read (and change) text files while respecting the encoding used for the text. I wish (for other API's)  to explicitly convert all read text to UTF-8 for internal use. 
Independent of what the actual encoding in the file was.

I am on windows and testing a textfile encoded using "ansi" "UTF-8" (those seem to work correctly). And then "unicode big endian" doesn't work; the `std::getline` result seems to be the raw byte array, no conversion of the file (UTF-16??) to UTF-8.

How can I force this? I do not know beforehand what the file is encoded with. Code used:

```
std::string retString;
if (isValidIndex(file_index) && OpenFilestreams()[file_index]->good()) {
    std::getline(*OpenFilestreams()[file_index], retString);
}
return retString;
```

Where file is `OpenFilestreams()` "is" a vector (static one containing all opened files), and `file_index` an index in the vector. So how to make sure here that it reads using the correct encoding?

---

As for the use:

Actually trying to convert it to a wstring using:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
return converter.from_bytes(input.c_str());
```

Gives the a `std::range_error` exception. (I need wstring for other windows api functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way that std::getline can get the encoding of the file. You can uses std::locale to change the encoding used.

Some Unicode files contain BOM (which state the encoding used), by this is not required.

Normally the text applications if the BOM is present use that encoding and if not try to make heuristics for identify the encoding used and read the text with that encoding, normalize the text (ex: UTF8), assume in the rest of the app the text is in UTF8, and saved in the same encoding that was read.

Some info about Unicode [Joel Spolsky Unicode Article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
Other Article about [Reading Unicode Encodings in C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38242/Reading-UTF-8-with-C-streams)

Comment: So what should I default to? Simply UTF8? I'm getting complaints that certain files -chinese- aren't read correctly by the library I created.

Comment: You could test reading with [UTF16 encoding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf16), but would be only to solve that problem with that specific encoding (ex: UTF16 Big Endian, and many others would still don't work).