# Convert UCS-2 inside character array to UTF-8 std::string

Tags: c++, string, unicode, utf-8

Well this is a direct "followup" of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790637/unicode-aware-stdgetline/24792782?noredirect=1#comment38481790_24792782) question; I decided to split the problem into two - Originally I posted the whole picture to prevent getting another close with "YZ problem". For now consider I know already the character encoding.

However I read a string using std::getline from a file. This file is encoded in a format I know -say UTF16 big endian-. 
But not "all" files are UTF16 (actually most are UTF8), I prefer to have as little code-copying as possible.

Now my first response is to "just read the bytes" and "then do the conversion to UTF-8", and skip the conversion if the input is already UTF-8. So I read it first into a `std::string` (please ignore the "ugglyness" of `OpenFilestreams()[file_index]`);

```
std::string retString;
if (isValidIndex(file_index) && OpenFilestreams()[file_index]->good()) {
    std::getline(*OpenFilestreams()[file_index], retString);
}
return retString;
```

After this I oblviously have a nonsense string - as the bytes are ordered as if the string was UCS2/UTF-16. So how can I convert this `std::string` to another `std::string` resulting in the UTF8-byte ordering. - Or should I do this at line reading level (or even at opening the file-stream level?)

I prefer to keep myself to the C++11 standard, maybe boost/ICU if it is really better (already have boots, but no ICU library at my pc).

Comment: they have good code samples on utf8everywhere.org

Comment: What is a "YZ problem"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit an advanced (+1) XY problem.